# How properly convert Guillotine to Canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas

I'm trying use [this](http://guillotine.js.org) plugin and convert to canvas on each image change.

What I'm not understanding is that when I execute all angles (at the same time) the image is settled in a good way.

```
var a = [0, 90, 180, 270];
a.forEach(function(angle) {
    data.angle = angle;
    _canvas(data, function(element) {
        callback(element);
        response.append(element);
    });
});
```

But when I use only the controls, the imagem just don't fit with the same result of the prev example.

```
_canvas(data, function(element) {
  callback(element);
  response.append(element);
});
```

I have the code [here](http://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/NxRdLb), you can switch the comments (lines 100-115) to see the results that I'm talking about it.

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Html5 canvas can certainly crop, scale & rotate an image. But it seems an unfair to ask us to convert a whole plugin for you. Instead, you can search previous Q&A on the `canvas` tag and you will find many examples showing how to crop, scale & rotate an image.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

What I was trying to do, was use [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/jquery-guillotine/bD1tPNcWd7k). And every time I thought that this example was broke, so I was struggling to resolve the canvas drawing calc.

Today, back to that link, i figure out:

```
$('#sample_picture');
```

and

```
$('#original_picture');
```

Must be two different elements and not one been use twice.

Anyway if anyone need canvas using this plugging [here is](http://codepen.io/rochapablo/pen/NxRdLb) one example and this time working as well.